# T-SQL: from rows to columns but not an actual pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

Is there a T-SQL (SQL Server 2008R2) query to transform `TABLE_1` into the expected resultset?

**TABLE_1**

```
+----------+-------------------------+---------+------+
| IdDevice | Timestamp               | M300    | M400 |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+------+
| 3        | 2012-12-05 16:29:51.000 | 2357,69 | 520  |
| 6        | 2012-12-05 16:29:51.000 | 1694,81 | 470  |
| 1        | 2012-12-05 16:29:51.000 | 2046,33 | 111  |
+----------+-------------------------+---------+------+
```

Expected resultset

```
+-------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
|        Timestamp        | 3_M300  | 3_M400 | 6_M300  | 6_M400 | 6_M300  | 6_M400 |
+-------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
| 2012-12-05 16:29:51.000 | 2357,69 |    520 | 1694,81 |    470 | 2046,33 |    111 |
+-------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: For the last two columns in the result do you mean to preface the name with a `6` or should it be `1`? Do you know all of the idDevices that you want to transform or is it unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still a `PIVOT` query but before you `PIVOT` you must perform an `UNPIVOT` of your columns.

First, you perform the `UNPIVOT` which takes your current multiple columns and transforms them into two columns - one with the value and the other with the column name. The key for the `UNPIVOT` is that the datatypes be the same, so in the subquery I `cast` any columns to the same datatype:

```
select timestamp,
    value, cast(iddevice as varchar(10)) + '_'+col as col
  from
  (
    select iddevice,
      timestamp,
      cast(m300 as varchar(10)) m300,
      cast(m400 as varchar(10)) m400
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (m300, m400)
  ) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/780f9/1)

Result:

```
|                       TIMESTAMP |   VALUE |    COL |
------------------------------------------------------
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 | 2357,69 | 3_m300 |
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 |     520 | 3_m400 |
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 | 1694,81 | 6_m300 |
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 |     470 | 6_m400 |
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 | 2046,33 | 1_m300 |
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 |     111 | 1_m400 |
```

Once you complete the unpivot, then you can apply the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select timestamp,
    value, cast(iddevice as varchar(10)) + '_'+col as col
  from
  (
    select iddevice,
      timestamp,
      cast(m300 as varchar(10)) m300,
      cast(m400 as varchar(10)) m400
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (m300, m400)
  ) unpiv
) src1
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([3_m300], [3_m400],
              [6_m300], [6_m400],
              [1_m300], [1_m400])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64d78/3)

Results:

```
|                       TIMESTAMP |  3_M300 | 3_M400 |  6_M300 | 6_M400 |  1_M300 | 1_M400 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| December, 05 2012 16:29:51+0000 | 2357,69 |    520 | 1694,81 |    470 | 2046,33 |    111 |
```

If you have an unknown number of `IdDevices` that you want to transform into columns, then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' 
                      + quotename(cast(t.IdDevice as varchar(10)) +'_'
                                  +c.name)
                    from yourtable t
                     cross apply sys.columns as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('yourtable') and
                         C.name not in ('IdDevice', 'Timestamp')
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT timestamp,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
               select timestamp,
                value, cast(iddevice as varchar(10)) + ''_''+col as col
              from
              (
                select iddevice,
                  timestamp,
                  cast(m300 as varchar(10)) m300,
                  cast(m400 as varchar(10)) m400
                from yourtable
              ) src
              unpivot
              (
                value
                for col in (m300, m400)
              ) unpiv
            ) x
            pivot
            (
              max(value)
              for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64d78/11)

Edit, if you need a totals field for each m value, then you can use:

```
select timestamp,
  [3_m300], [3_m400],
  [6_m300], [6_m400],
  [1_m300], [1_m400],
  [1_m300] + [3_m300] + [6_m300] Total_m300,
  [1_m400] + [3_m400] + [6_m400] Total_m400
from
(
  select timestamp,
    value, cast(iddevice as varchar(10)) + '_'+col as col
  from
  (
    select iddevice,
      timestamp,
      m300,
      m400
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (m300, m400)
  ) unpiv
) src1
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for col in ([3_m300], [3_m400],
              [6_m300], [6_m400],
              [1_m300], [1_m400])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cfeb5/2)

Comment: Your answer is excellent.
I need a further step: using columns in a formula. Example: 1_M300 + 3_M300 + 6_300 (+ is an SUM and not a concatenation).